# NSDateFormatter MMM conversion

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nsdate, nsdateformatter

As before XCode 9 I had no issue regarding DateFormatter.

With the update I have a issue I do not seem to be able to bypass.

I am busy converting dates from NSString to NSDate, however my code seems to not be able to initialize the NSDate.

My Code:

```
NSString *testdate = @"Sep 20 2017  1:46PM"; // this is how my date looks

NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setDateFormat:@"MMM dd yyyy hh:mma"]; 

NSDate *thisDate = [df dateFromString: testdate]; // this returns nil
```

I have tried manipulating the string in various ways, and only after I turned the function I found the dateformat issue to have appeared.

Has anyone found this issue and a possible solution?

Edit:

The only device I have this on is a iPhone 7 with iOS 11 (two different devices was tested and iPhone 7 with iOS 10 is also working correctly). I have an iPhone 6 plus as well as an iPhone 7 Plus which are both on iOS 11, and both these are working... with the time format

When I convert the [NSDate date] to string with the same date formatter my result is: M09 20 2017 1:46PM... - this was a date format issue it seems(seems to have happened when I changed the timeformat to test) and is now working however is not the problem to my issue

Comment: can you show the code related to this `[NSDate date] `

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik the conversion is now correct from date to string however string to date still fails

Comment: date does not produce the exact answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After closer investigation it seems like if I have setup a DateFormatter I also need to add a Locale to get it to work... The dates I got from a server so I can't just change it, due to being used on a website as well.

I received the date from the server as AM/PM and the Locale solved the issue

```
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setDateFormat:@"MMM dd yyyy hh:mma"];
[df setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"]];
```

This solved the issue that I had.

Comment: This change would be needed under any version of iOS or Xcode if the user's locale was set to any language other than English.

Comment: Ok I have not prior run into this problem... only now... but its good to know... for checking in future... Thank you